# How to usa a for slice in a Dataframe row by row in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, for-loop, row

I'm new in Python and I'm working in a web automation for **scraping** some data and help me to analyse.

So, I have this data in a data frame such as:

```
 Name    site data1    site data2    SiteID
name1       23 ins       43 vid     082820399
name2       67 ins        3 vid     996820344
name3       55 ins       67 vid     201988493
```

With selenium **scrape** the data, but what I need is to make a function that select each row in SiteID column for my function, where the **scrape** run.

I've tried to make a for slice in the begining, I've tried to use '.iterrows' and '.iteritems', I've tried to use 'apply' in the for slice, but nothing works.

What occur is the page opening, but without any URL.

My code is like:

```
df = pd.read_csv('channel_data.csv')
df1 = df['SiteID']


class Channel_DSO:
    for links, row in df1.iterrows():
        def canais_dados():
        
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(
            'C:/chromedriver_win32_3/chromedriver.exe')
        for link in links:
            driver.get('{}/site?param=0&flow'.format(links))
            content = driver.page_source.encode ('utf-8').strip()
            soup = BeautifulSoup (content, 'lxml')
            site_detail = []
            detail = soup.find_all('a', id='site-detail')
            for detail in details:
                site_detail.append(details.text)

            link_detail = []
            l_details = soup.find_all('span', class_='link-detail-text') 
            for l_detail in l_details:
                link_detail.append(l_details.text)

         
            sites_data = []
            for detail, l_detail in zip(site_detail, link_detail):
                sites_data.append(
                {'Site': detail, 'L detail': l_detail})
         driver.quit()
```

I don't know what to do and I was searching for any responses in the web.

I'm sorry if the question is so noob and if I talk something wrong...

Hope someone can help me...thanks!!

**Edit**: I've write scrap instead scrape (thanks barny); also I see another mistake in my code: "df1 = df['SiteID']" I've selcting another column, but it doesn’t affect the result. So sorry, wish not to disturb you.

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ (and __scraper__, __scraping__, __scraped__) not scrap. ‘To scrap’ means to throw away like rubbish. Edits highlighted in __bold__

Comment: Thanks @barny. So sorry about this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a soluction...just creating another 'def' function inside the class.

My soluction works well and I can iterate every row in the dataframe.

How it works:

```
df = pd.read_csv('channel_data.csv')
df1 = df['SiteID']


class __init__: 
    def canais_dados():   
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        'C:/chromedriver_win32_3/chromedriver.exe')
    for link in links:
        driver.get('{}/site?param=0&flow'.format(links))
        content = driver.page_source.encode ('utf-8').strip()
        soup = BeautifulSoup (content, 'lxml')
        site_detail = [] 
        detail = soup.find_all('a', id='site-detail')
        for detail in details:
            site_detail.append(details.text)

        link_detail = []
        l_details = soup.find_all('span', class_='link-detail-text') 
        for l_detail in l_details:
            link_detail.append(l_details.text)

     
        sites_data = []
        for detail, l_detail in zip(site_detail, link_detail):
            sites_data.append(
                {'Site': detail, 'L detail': l_detail})
    driver.quit()

    def links_loop:
        for links in links:
            loop = next(links.iteritem[i+1])
            if loop == False:
                links_loop.exit()
            elif loop == True:
                exec(canais_dados)
```

Its working well.
Thanks to everyone and sorry to diturb or about any mistake.